# Hosting python-telegram-bot on Heroku always Conflict after a few seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, bots, python-telegram-bot

I setup a telegram bot using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and I want to host it on Heroku. The problem is the server code always error, claiming that there's another bot instance running (which there is none).

I created a `Procfile` like so:

```
web: python main.py
```

and made sure `requirements.txt` is up to date.

main.py:

```py
# ... handlers ...

updater = Updater(token=os.environ['TOKEN'], use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s  %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help))


print('Started Bot. Listening for messages...')
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Here's the error log:

```
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096562+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-04-24 16:20:34,095  telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.

2020-04-24T16:20:34.096564+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096564+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 380, in _network_loop_retry
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096565+00:00 app[web.1]:     if not action_cb():
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096565+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 341, in polling_action_cb
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096609+00:00 app[web.1]:     allowed_updates=allowed_updates)
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096610+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<decorator-gen-31>", line 2, in get_updates
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096610+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 70, in decorator
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096611+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096611+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 2136, in get_updates
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096612+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = self._request.post(url, data, timeout=float(read_latency) + float(timeout))
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096612+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 334, in post
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096612+00:00 app[web.1]:     **urlopen_kwargs)
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096613+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 249, in _request_wrapper
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096613+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise Conflict(message)
2020-04-24T16:20:34.096946+00:00 app[web.1]: telegram.error.Conflict: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
2020-04-24T16:20:34.523514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I made sure to stop any other running `main.py`'s.

So how do I properly host the bot instance on Heroku?

Comment: I have an alternative solution which is by using webhooks: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku
BUT when the bot instance is live in heroku, and someone starts a local server using `updater.start_polling` , the bot instance at heroku stops listening until another re-deploy. I'm still looking for an answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instead "web"- "worker".
It was a solution for my bot on heroku.